# Access NextCloud-Files within Host (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: pi-2, nextcloud

When running a NextCloud server on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian, how do I access the the synchronised files on that Raspberry Pi without using the browser?

The data folder of NextCloud returns that access permission is denied. For me that is located in `/var/www/html/nextcloud/data`. However, I would like to record camera images with a python script, save them in a local folder and have it automatically be synchronised. Strangely, I have not found a solution while searching for 5 hours. How can I save files locally onto my NextCloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the data directory locally, nextcloud will complain if you change the permissions or add files directly as an anti tampering measure. To do what you describe you'll need to use webdav and mount nextcloud as a webdav share on the pi and then you'll be able to save files straight to it via that folder.